# categorize errors & warnings in logs

Tags: python, shell, awk, grep

I wanted to categorize the errors in my log files. I have many folders(~100) and each of them has a log file. I want to be able to parse all the log files and categorize different errors with their frequency. The log would have following format

2014-10-22 07:55:02,997 ERROR log_message [optional_stack_trace]

One approach is to first parse all the log statements having ERROR and putting them in a single file. Ideally the resultant file will have just the log_messages without the date & ERROR strings. I guess I can just group similar strings after that. What do you guys think? Any cleaner and better approach?

Comment: may I ask why negative vote?

Comment: The question is too broad

Comment: @user2812714 Generally questions of the format "How do I <complicated task>?" are not the type of question that belong on SO. This format is much better suited for specific programming problems due to the delayed nature of the responses. So my advice would be to start coding something you think would work and come back when you run into a problem.

Comment: @user2812714 About your statement "[storing] without the date & ERROR strings", I disagree because while ERROR is redundant the dates **do add** information to your log, eg., you can sort the contents on error times and so on.  OTOH if you name the log say `2014-10-24.errors,` then you've extracted some info into the filename and you can get away with the date part of the datetime string.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want something like this (using GNU awk for true 2-d arrays):

```
$ awk '{cnt[$3][$4]++} END{for (err in cnt) for (msg in cnt[err]) print err, msg, cnt[err][msg]}' file1 file2 ...
```

but since you didn't post any sample input and expected output, it's a guess.